# Wanting to copy from one sheet to another, based on values in one column

Tags: excel, vba, copying

I have an estimate sheet and an invoice.  I am trying to write code to search the units column ("L") in the estimate sheet.  When a number is found, copy the description from a different column ("A") to the invoice sheet in a certain range.  I am able to get the search to loop through column L and it can determine whether the number is >0.  It will even copy the first description over to the invoice.  But, it will not copy anything over beyond that.  I am looking for help please.  Here is my code thus far.

```
Sub CopyToInvoice()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim rng_dest As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    i = 1
    Set rng_dest = Sheets("Estimate").Range("L5")
    'Find first cell with value in column L on sheet Estimate
    Range("L5").Select
    Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng_dest.Rows(i)) = 100
    i = i + 1
    Set rng = Sheets("Invoice").Range("C22:C36")
    'Copy rows containing values to sheet Invoice
    For a = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
      If ActiveCell.Value > 0 Then
       Sheets("Estimate").Range("A5").Copy Sheets("Invoice").Range("C22")
      End If
        'Step down 1 row from present location
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
       i = i + 1
     Next a
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: If this needs to be a lookup, there should be 4 columns involved, 2 per worksheet. For simplicity's sake, let's make them A, B, and C, D for source and destination respectively. You loop through Destination C to find a match in Source A. If found, you copy Source B to Destination D. Related to your code, you loop through `Invoice C` to find a match in `Estimate L`. If found, you copy `Estimate A` to `Invoice ?`. Your code kind of hints that `?` is `C`, but that would overwrite the values in `C` (which is valid). Are you sure you want to do this? Please, confirm or suggest another column.

Comment: Invoice C is blank.  I want to complete the Invoice based on entries into the Estimate L, copying over from Estimate A to Invoice C.

Answer (score 0):

You are pasting to same line in Invoice sheet in each iteration.

Replace your line:

`Sheets("Estimate").Range("A5").Copy Sheets("Invoice").Range("C22")`

with

`Sheets("Estimate").Range("A" & 4 + a).Copy Sheets("Invoice").Range("C" & 21 + a)`

Comment: Running your code line by line with `F8` will help you solve these puzzles.  See what vba does in your excel after each line.

Comment: I am using "Step-in" to watch what happens.  With your suggested change, the value copied over is "0" vs. the description in column A.  And it skips the same number as empty rows.

Answer (score 0):

### Write From Another Column If Criteria Met

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyToInvoice()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Estimate")
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    If slRow < 5 Then Exit Sub ' no data in column range
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Invoice")
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range("C22")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 5 To slRow ' rows in 'L'
        If IsNumeric(sws.Cells(r, "L").Value) Then ' numeric
            If sws.Cells(r, "L").Value > 0 Then ' check 'L>0'
                dCell.Value = sws.Cells(r, "A").Value ' write 'A' to destination
                Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1) ' next destination
            'Else ' L <= 0
            End If
        'Else ' not numeric
        End If
    Next r
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked exactly!!  Thank you very much!